# Space delimiter in CSV import to Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter, separator

I know there are more than a few questions regarding space delimiters in CSV files.

I have a CSV file that appears to be separated by a space. When importing to Python, I have tried every code out there to identify space as a delimiter. However, I keep getting error messages. For example:

```
    test_filepath = 'test_data.csv'

with codecs.open(test_filepath, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:  # import UTF8 based csv file 
    test_df = pd.read_table( file, delim_whitespace=True )
```

this yields the following error:

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

when I try this:

```
    test_filepath = 'test_data.csv'

with codecs.open(test_filepath, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:  # import UTF8 based csv file 
    test_df = pd.read_table( file, delimiter=" " )
```

it gives the same error.

when i try this:

```
    test_filepath = 'test_data.csv'

with codecs.open(test_filepath, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:  # import UTF8 based csv file 
    test_df = pd.read_table( file, sep = "/s+" )
```

I get the same error.

When I try this:

```
        test_filepath = 'test_data.csv'

with codecs.open(test_filepath, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:  # import UTF8 based csv file 
    test_df = pd.read_table( file, delimiter='\t')
```

I get the same error.

the ONLY WAY I dont get an error is if I do this:

```
        test_filepath = 'test_data.csv'

with codecs.open(test_filepath, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:  # import UTF8 based csv file 
    test_df = pd.read_table( file, delimiter=',')
```

but the results look completely off, and test_df.info() shows that only one column is created (there should be like 100 columns).

Comment: does it have headers?

Comment: How do you know your data is space-delimited? Have you opened your data and looked at? Your traceback seems to think you don't have any data.

Comment: open it in excel and make it space delimited

Comment: @ubuntu_noob the file has header columns, but it is in a foreign language. Im using codecs to handle the utf8 issue...

Comment: @Joel I opened the data in a text editor, and I did not see any delimiters like commas or anything else. the values were separated by spaces only...

Comment: What happens when you try to open your data using the built-in `csv` module?

Comment: Instead of wildly guessing at what kind of whitespace you have, why not actually read one of the rows (just `row = file.readline()`) and then `print repr(row)` and actually _see_ what you have?

Comment: Also, you need to read the docs more carefully. `/s+` doesn't mean anything—or, rather, it means you want to separate columns with a literal slash and then one or more letter `s`s, which isn't very useful.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include a copy/paste of say the first 10 lines of your CSV file, we would then be able to help better.

Comment: are you sure you are not dealing with a Fixed-Width file here?

Answer (score 5):

I think pandas might do the trick, one of these should work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)  
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=' ')
```