# multiple spacedelimited txt file iport to python

Tags: python, import

I am starting with some simple data analysis using python (Spider). However I am really struggling to import my data to python.
The dataset is a TXT file  from like this (many more rows):

```
   0.03100     0.00061     0.03100    -0.00053  
   0.06300    -0.00174     0.06300    -0.00075  
   0.09400     0.00628     0.09400    -0.00089  
   0.12500     0.01292     0.12500    -0.00111  
   0.15600    -0.00027     0.15600     0.00015  
   0.18800    -0.00319     0.18800     0.00108  
   0.21900    -0.00733     0.21900    -0.00070  
.........
```

I just want to choose two columns analyze and plot them.

I am using all sorts of possibilities with open, genfromtx, pd.read_csv, loadtxt and others but nothing really works.
the closest I got was using:

```
data=np.genfromtxt('C1.txt' , delimiter=' ')
```

but it gives me error

```
Line #2 (got 8 columns instead of 9)
Line #7 (got 8 columns instead of 9)
```

using loadtxt
give me error: could not convert string '' to float64 at row 0, column 1.

I saw other peple having problems with the same but nothing helped me to move forward -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549448/space-delimiter-in-csv-import-to-python

I am grateful for any suggestion, thank you all in advance

I expected to load data so I can work with them but the import to python is just painful compared to minutes it takes in origin or Matlab

Comment: Does every row in the file contain 4 values?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the entire file as a list of lists (float) as follows:

```
values = []

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt') as foo:
    for line in foo:
        values.append(list(map(float, line.split())))

print(values)
```

Thus, from the sample data in the question, this would give you:

```
[[0.031, 0.00061, 0.031, -0.00053], [0.063, -0.00174, 0.063, -0.00075], [0.094, 0.00628, 0.094, -0.00089], [0.125, 0.01292, 0.125, -0.00111], [0.156, -0.00027, 0.156, 0.00015], [0.188, -0.00319, 0.188, 0.00108], [0.219, -0.00733, 0.219, -0.0007]]
```

...which will be trivial to process

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer it is working without even using pandas or anything: can you please explain more how did you come up with the logic behind code?

Comment: This code reads the file one line at a time. Each line is tokenised on whitespace. Each token is converted to float. A list of lists is constructed. No need for additional modules for something so trivial

Comment: thanks for the answer, so how does this map command work here?

Comment: @IgorMoravčík https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: also when I put a random data to make a 2 row string and try to use line.split it doesnt work and gives: NameError: name 'line' is not defined. So how line.split work in in loop?

Comment: @IgorMoravčík https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split Also, there is no way that you can get a NameError exception with the code shown in my answer

Comment: I saw the documentation for the map function but I dont understant it at all... anyway I will try to study